# Why is this script not working as it should?

Tags: lua, roblox

Im trying to do a script that prints a NumValue's Value everytime it changes.

i tried:

```
local Shards = workspace.ads.Amarelo.Shards
local ShardsValue = workspace.ads.Amarelo.Shards.Value
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer

function update()
local newValue = ShardsValue
print(newValue)

end
update()

Shards.Changed:Connect(function()
update()
end)
```

but it just keeps printing me 0 even though the value is another number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumberValue is not changing in Roblox Workspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845478/numbervalue-is-not-changing-in-roblox-workspace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the connect function to something like, see if it will print the new values.

```
Shards.Changed:Connect(function(newValue)
print(newValue)
end)
```